# Assigning to 'id<UIWebViewDelegate> _Nullable' from incompatible type 'WebView *const __strong'

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview

When I added **webView.delegate = self;**  to a web view in the following code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-64)];
    NSString *htmlFile = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:USER_CODE];
     NSLog(@"Value retured : %@",htmlFile);
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:htmlFile];
    webView.delegate = self;
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
}
```

I got the following error.

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/iOS/SchoolApp/test/WebView/WebView.m:25:22: Assigning to 'id<UIWebViewDelegate> _Nullable' from incompatible type 'WebView *const __strong'
```

Comment: Is `WebView` the name of your `UIViewController` subclass? If so, you should declare it to conform to the `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol, as Anbu.Karthik points out. If `WebView` is not a `UIViewController` subclass, then the use of `viewDidLoad` doesn't make sense. (As an aside, if it is a `UIViewController` subclass, `WebView` is a confusing name to use for the class, because it doesn't indicate it's a view controller, and instead sounds like it's a view, or even a `UIWebView` subclass.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your View controller does not implement the **UIWebViewDelegate** protocol.don't have it in your interface declaration on your class

```
@interface YourViewControllerName : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
```

Comment: as your current VC name is `WebView`